# Rider on M1 MacBook Air can't resolve symbols

Tags: c#, .net, macos, rider, apple-m1

I recently switched to a M1 Macbook Air and tried installing JetBrains Rider, but when I'm trying to run a hello world i get the errors below
[image]

i am running it through rosetta 2 and can't seem to find the problem

Comment: Don't expect everything to work flawlessly before the end of 2021.

Comment: sure @LexLi , but i hoped i could run a hello world at least :))

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is not related to M1. You would get the same error on any platform, because you put your Console.WriteLine function directly into class, you don't have it in any method, preferably Main()

Answer (score 1):

FWIW I am able to run C# programs through VS Code just fine on my M1 MacBook Air

[image]

I think it could be because you are missing your main() method?